# elastic beanstalk deploy has error

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to deploy my code to elastic beanstalk,

There is error:

And I don't know what's the problem,Please help me. Thank you!!

```
Command /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python27 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/opt/python/run/venv/build/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-tgTtHY-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/python/run/venv/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /opt/python/run/venv/build/lxml
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
2015-01-13 06:25:55,467 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --use-mirrors -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 36, in main
    install_dependencies()
  File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 31, in install_dependencies
    check_call('%s install --use-mirrors -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 505, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --use-mirrors -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

.ebextensions/01.config

```
packages:
    yum:
        gcc: ''
        python27-devel: ''
        postgresql93-devel: ''
        pkgconfig: ''
        libffi-devel: ''
        libxslt-devel: ''
        libxml2-devel: ''
```

Comment: Did you look at the log file in /root/.pip/pip.log to see what it said?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the logs and see which package is giving you the issue, it's likely just wanting you to allow-external and allow-unverified. Above the line in your requirements.txt where you have declared your package, do tthe following:

`--allow-external ExternalPackage
--allow-unverified ExternalPackage
ExternalPackage`

Hope this helps. You can see more examples at - https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format

Answer (score 0):

I know this issue is a bit dated, but wanted to throw in my fix just in case someone else out there is still having issues.

Not sure if this is exactly the issue you were having, but EBS kept rejecting my external python package that I wanted to install. So I removed the external package from my requirements.txt file and instead added some commands to my .ebextenions

Here is what I added, and it worked flawlessly.

`packages:
  yum:
    git: []

container_commands:
    01_install_infusionsoft:
        command: "pip install git+https://github.com/infusionsoft/Official-API-Python-Library.git"`

Not sure if this is the recommended way to work with EBS, but it was the easiest way to get my packages installed. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much . Although I'm not using elastic beanstalk now. Still very thank you